# Geoclusters in SOLR

Tags: solr, geospatial, markerclusterer

We're reimplementing a search that includes locations that need to be clustered on a map.  I've been searching without luck for an implementation in SOLR.

The current search with map clustering implemented is at http://www.uship.com/find

Has anyone seen similar or have ideas about how to best do this?

Regards,
Nick

Answer (score 6):

If the requirement is to cluster a fairly small number of points, perhaps less than 1000, then  Solr needn't be involved.  Grab the points and plot them using something like [HeatmapJS](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/).

I presume the requirement is to cluster *all* results in a search which may potentially be many thousands or even millions of documents.  I suggest starting with generating a heatmap of the densities over a grid of the search area.  You can do this by indexing each point encoded in geohash form at each length (e.g. D2RY, D2R, D2, D).  But then precede the length by how long it is: 4_D2RY, 3_D2R, 2_D2, 1_D.  These little strings go into a multi-valued "string" type field in Solr that you will then facet on.  When faceting, you'll come up with a suitable grid resolution (e.g. goehash prefix length) and then use that as a prefix query, like facet.prefix=4_  You can index the point using a LatLonType field separately and do a standard bounding box query there.  At this point, you're faceted search results will give you the information to fill in a grid of numbers.  The beauty of this scheme is that it is *fast* -- you could generate such heat-maps on the fly.  It will use a fair amount of RAM though since this is faceting on a multi-valued field that will have a ton of values.  This is something I want to add to the new Lucene spatial module (or perhaps at the Solr layer) in a way that won't need extra memory and to make it easy.  It won't make it to Solr 4.0, but maybe 4.1.

At this stage, perhaps a heatmap is fine as-is.  But you may want to apply clustering on top of this, as your question states.  Someone tipped me off to some [interesting geo clustering algorithms](http://web.archive.org/web/20071121140547/http://trib.tv/tech/clustering-points-on-a-google-map/) that can be applied to heatmaps.

Comment: Nope. Long ago I would have bet money on it being a priority but it just hasn't been.

Comment: This is a really neat solution. Did you come up with that solution yourself? I had to read it about 5 times before I understood how it works...

Comment: I did (I think).  A tweak to the approach is to put the each geohash substring into a separate field corresponding to its length -- ex: a "geohash_4" field with the value "D2RY".  No need for facet.prefix now.  If your data is single-valued, these would then be single-valued fields, unlike the original approach described.  This approach has different memory & performance characteristics, and realtime-search friendliness (better).  Another thing to experiment with is to index with doc-values and look at the memory & performance again in Solr 4.2.

Comment: Since SOLR 5.1 is released it is in the build (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-6191) Ref http://lucene.apache.org/core/5_1_0/changes/Changes.html#v5.1.0.new_features. However it is hard to find the way.

Comment: Author of the item is same as author of this answer!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether you searched lucidworks, but there are many interesting resources there:

[Search with Polygons: Another Approach to Solr Geospatial Search](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BtpBBFeZeeU)

Go through these:
http://www.lucidimagination.com/search/?q=geospatial#%2Fn

Already implemented in Solr:
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch/ (what's wrong with this approach?)
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearchDev 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3304